# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence C++

Tags: c++, oracle, fetch

So I can not figure out what is wrong why it keeps throwing this ORA-01002:

```
/**

//  compile: oracleCC fileName
//  Execute  a hardCoded sql query


/**  Program run snapshot

Connected to ORACLE as user: sp201511@cs11g

Query is  select supplierName from Supplier  where supplierNumber = 1

supplier name = Ray

*/


#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// Parse=partial by default when code=cpp so, preprocessor directives are
// recognized and parsed fully.
#define     UNAME_LEN      20
#define     PWD_LEN        40

// Declare section is required when CODE=CPP and/or PARSE={PARTIAL|NONE}
exec sql begin declare section;
  VARCHAR username[UNAME_LEN];  // VARCHAR is an ORACLE supplied struct
                                // Has actual data & length
  varchar password[PWD_LEN];    // varchar can be in lower case also
  varchar sql_statement[1000];  //holds the sql stat being constructed..
  int supplierNo;
  char    inputSupplierName[50];        //entered using cin
  varchar outputSupplierName[50];       //retrieved output from database

exec sql end declare section;

// Declare error handling function
void sql_error(char *msg);
void connectToDatabase();
void commitAndExit() ;
void buildAhardCodedSQL();
void prepareAndExecuteIt ();
exec sql include sqlca;

main()
{

//  Call sql_error() function on any error in an embedded SQL statement
    exec sql WHENEVER SQLERROR DO sql_error("Oracle error");


    exec sql
        WHENEVER SQLERROR
        DO sql_error("ORACLE error:");
    connectToDatabase();

    buildAhardCodedSQL();
    prepareAndExecuteIt ();
    commitAndExit();

}

void connectToDatabase() {

/*  Hardcoded username and password  */
    strcpy((char *)username.arr,"myusername");
    strcpy((char *)password.arr,"password.");
    username.len = strlen((char *) username.arr);
    password.len = strlen((char *) password.arr);

//  CONNECTS TO DATABASE
    exec sql CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password;

    cout << "\nConnected to ORACLE as user: "
                << (char *)username.arr << endl << endl;

}


void commitAndExit() {

    exec sql commit work release;
    exit(0);
}
void sql_error(char *msg)
{
    exec sql WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE;
    cout << endl << msg << endl;
    cout << sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc << endl;
    exec sql rollback release;
    exit(1);
}

void buildAhardCodedSQL() {
    strcpy((char *)sql_statement.arr,"select supplierNumber, supplierName ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"from supplier ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"where supplierNumber < > 1;");
    // Display the SQL statement and its current input host variable.
    cout << "Query is  " << (char *) sql_statement.arr << endl;
}
void  prepareAndExecuteIt() {

//  Prepare the query; define a cursor, execute it...

    sql_statement.len = strlen((char *) sql_statement.arr);
    exec sql PREPARE S1 FROM :sql_statement;

/* The declare statement associates a cursor with a
 * PREPAREd statement.  The cursor name, like the statement
 * name, does not appear in the Declare Section.
 * A single cursor name can not be declared more than once.
*/

    exec sql declare C1 cursor FOR S1;

    exec sql open C1;

    exec sql FETCH C1 INTO :supplierNo, :outputSupplierName;

     if ( sqlca.sqlcode !=  0) {
        cout << "past fetch..." <<endl;

        cout << sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc << endl;
        exec sql rollback release;
        exit(1);
     }
     cout << "supplier name = " << (char *)outputSupplierName.arr << endl;
     cout << "supplier number = " << supplierNo << endl;
   exec sql close C1;
}
```

It complies and everything but the output is

past fetch....

ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

ive tried so many things im losing it guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch is failing because the open, declare and prepare all failed before that point, but you didn't check for any errors from those. If you did you'd get an `ORA-00911: invalid character` error, because of this:

```
    strcpy((char *)sql_statement.arr,"select supplierNumber, supplierName ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"from supplier ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"where supplierNumber < > 1;");
```

The statement that builds is

```
select supplierNumber, supplierName from supplier where supplierNumber < > 1;
```

But then you do:

```
exec sql PREPARE S1 FROM :sql_statement;
```

As with dynamic SQL and JDBC calls, this prepare can only take a single statement. The semicolon at the end of your constructed string is a statement separator which doesn't have any meaning in this context, and it is invalid as far as the parser is concerned.

So just remove that semicolon:

```
    strcpy((char *)sql_statement.arr,"select supplierNumber, supplierName ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"from supplier ");
    strcat((char *)sql_statement.arr,"where supplierNumber < > 1");
```

and add an error check after each `exec sql`.